# Drawing a tournament bracket (CSS/HTML based on PHP Dataset)

Tags: php, html, css, tournament

If you're not familiar with what I mean by tournament bracket, see here:
http://baseballguru.com/bracket1.gif

That said, I have built the dataset and figured out the number of rounds (ceil(log($numPlayers,2))) and I am comfortable finding the number of players in each round, etc.

What I need to do now is move my array of matches for each round into a bracket.  Be it CSS, or tabled, I can play with the design myself, I'm just wondering how I should go about building this (consider the tournament can have a variable number of rounds) into something visual.

Thanks!

Comment: I worked on a PHP / Laravel plugin that generates brackets with / without preliminary round robin. Maybe it can be useful to you, I don't know what tech you are using. Here is the github. 

https://github.com/xoco70/kendo-tournaments

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with tables and set appropriate `rowspan`s to line up the bracket. This is the easier way, but some will say not semantically correct. [Example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showpost.php?p=518050&postcount=11).

You could also do it with CSS'd layers by simply calculating appropriate positions and using absolutely positioned divs to make it look like a bracket. Note that this approach won't be fluid unless you move it around by javascript. [More on this](http://www.breathingfire.com/2008/03/nba-playoffs-bracket-hows-it-work/).

Finally, you could do it with nested lists, as described in [this topic](http://csscreator.com/node/32626), but that looks quite messy.

Comment: I used the first example with tables, but managed to duplicate it on both sides.  Thanks.

Any advice on a cleaner way to generate the table though?

Answer (score 3):

I have a project ([TournamentsApi](http://tournaments.codeplex.com)) that was made for tracking and rendering tournaments. You should take a look at it.

On my site, I'm rendering the brackets to SVG and embedding them in the HTML.  I'd be happy to share the code I use for the SVG generation / embedding, if you were inclined to use my implementation.

Of course, mine is written in C#, so it may not suit you uses.  However, the source code was released under the MIT license, and you are free to use the data structures I have created for your own project

Comment: hey John, was wondering if you were able to finish this project? would love to see and get an idea from your code on how I should approach my problems with generating brackets.

Comment: @gdubs, the Tournaments API project is more-or-less complete.  Here it is in action on our website: http://lanlordz.net/Events/ViewTournament/8/modern-warfare-2  (scroll down on the rounds list to see it rendered as SVG.)

Comment: hey John, is there any chance I can have the source code for that? been experimenting with jquery and it's been a real pain, was wondering if there would be a c# version of it. Thank you!

Comment: Yeha, the link in the answer has the code to the actual bracket generation code.  Implementing it in HTML with a database backing it is in the LAN Lordz source code. http://lanlordz.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -3):

If you are up for a quick and dirty solution with No CSS or java needed. try this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43939704/TournamentBrackets.7z

It's just HTML DIV's and a few .png files for the lines (see the 7Z file for pics).

Grtz,
Theo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" >
<head>
  <title>Boom16 - dubbele afvalling </title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Div info -->

    <div id="DivInfo"  style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:930px; width:300px; height:60px; "><FONT SIZE="10" COLOR="000000">DIVISIE 1</FONT></div>

<!-- Scheiding -->

    <div id="Scheiding"  style="position:absolute; top:604px; left:0px; width:926px; height:2x; border:2px solid #000; "></div>
    <div id="ST1"        style="position:absolute; top:585px; left:10px; width:200px; height:60px; "><FONT SIZE="3" COLOR="000000">Normale races<br>Herkansings races</FONT></div>


<!-- Lijnen -->

    <div id="H"    style="position:absolute; top:606px; left:1132px;width:24px; height:2x;     border:2px solid #000; "></div>
    <div id="HL2"  style="position:absolute; top:315px; left:900px; width:130px; height:260px; background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL3"  style="position:absolute; top:635px; left:900px; width:130px; height:260px; background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL4"  style="position:absolute; top:145px; left:670px; width:130px; height:110px; background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL5"  style="position:absolute; top:785px; left:670px; width:130px; height:110px; background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL6"  style="position:absolute; top:315px; left:670px; width:130px; height:110px; background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL7"  style="position:absolute; top:955px; left:670px; width:130px; height:110px; background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL8"  style="position:absolute; top:75px;  left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL9"  style="position:absolute; top:715px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL10" style="position:absolute; top:175px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL11" style="position:absolute; top:815px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL12" style="position:absolute; top:355px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL13" style="position:absolute; top:995px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Rood1.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL14" style="position:absolute; top:455px; left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL15" style="position:absolute; top:1095px;left:440px; width:130px; height:40px;  background-image: url(Blauw1.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL16" style="position:absolute; top:30px;  left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL17" style="position:absolute; top:670px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL18" style="position:absolute; top:105px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL19" style="position:absolute; top:745px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL20" style="position:absolute; top:170px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL21" style="position:absolute; top:810px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL22" style="position:absolute; top:245px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL23" style="position:absolute; top:885px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL24" style="position:absolute; top:310px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL25" style="position:absolute; top:950px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL26" style="position:absolute; top:385px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL27" style="position:absolute; top:1025px;left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL28" style="position:absolute; top:1090px;left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL28" style="position:absolute; top:450px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Rood3.png);  background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL30" style="position:absolute; top:525px; left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>
    <div id="HL31" style="position:absolute; top:1165px;left:210px; width:130px; height:15px;  background-image: url(Blauw3.png); background-size:100% 100%;"></div>

<!-- Blokken -->

    <div id="H0"  style="position:absolute; top:575px; left:1160px;width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H0  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H1"  style="position:absolute; top:575px; left:930px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H1  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H2"  style="position:absolute; top:255px; left:700px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H2  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H3"  style="position:absolute; top:895px; left:700px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H3  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H4"  style="position:absolute; top:115px; left:470px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H4  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H5"  style="position:absolute; top:755px; left:470px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H5  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H6"  style="position:absolute; top:395px; left:470px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H6  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H7"  style="position:absolute; top:1035px;left:470px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H7  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H8"  style="position:absolute; top:45px ; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H8  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H9"  style="position:absolute; top:685px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H9  R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H10" style="position:absolute; top:185px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H10 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H11" style="position:absolute; top:825px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H11 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H12" style="position:absolute; top:325px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H12 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H13" style="position:absolute; top:965px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H13 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H14" style="position:absolute; top:465px; left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H14 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H15" style="position:absolute; top:1105px;left:240px; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H15 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H16" style="position:absolute; top:10px;  left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H16 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H17" style="position:absolute; top:650px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H17 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H18" style="position:absolute; top:80px;  left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H18 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H19" style="position:absolute; top:720px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H19 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H20" style="position:absolute; top:150px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H20 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H21" style="position:absolute; top:790px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H21 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H22" style="position:absolute; top:220px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H22 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H23" style="position:absolute; top:860px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H23 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H24" style="position:absolute; top:290px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H24 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H25" style="position:absolute; top:930px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H25 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H26" style="position:absolute; top:360px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H26 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H27" style="position:absolute; top:1000px;left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H27 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H28" style="position:absolute; top:1070px;left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H28 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H28" style="position:absolute; top:430px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Flying dutch 1<br>H28 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Brabo TD 1    </FONT></div>
    <div id="H30" style="position:absolute; top:500px; left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H30 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>
    <div id="H31" style="position:absolute; top:1140px;left:10px ; width:200px; height:60px; border:1px solid #000; "><FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="000000">Brabo TD 1    <br>H31 R: 19,11 B: 20,01<br>Flying dutch 1</FONT></div>


</body>
</html>
```