# How to create a cup tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i dont know how to create a cup tree with html and javascript.
I have some columns for the rounds

```
Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 | Final
```

and than again three new columns for the matches

```
teamA
result
teamB


teamA
result
teamB


teamA
result
teamB
```

in te next columns the matches are less.
I want to create the tree programmatic but i dont how to handle the different spaces between the macthes because in every round they are bigger. I dont know how to calculate that.

Does someone of you have an idea how to do that?

This is what i did until now

```
<div class="yui3-u-1-4 tourneyMatchColumn">
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
  <div class="match">
    <div class="home">sdsd</div>
    <div class="result">2:1</div>
    <div class="away">sdfedf</div>
  </div>
  <div class="matchspacerStart"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is a cup tree?  you want to draw up some kind of tournament bracket in HTML?

Comment: @jon, [Here it is](http://www.chessdom.com/images/store/pairings-16055.jpg)

Comment: how many teams?  only powers of 2 go smoothly, otherwise you need bye's

Comment: i wanna make it configurable between 8,16,32 and 64 teams

Comment: @blasteralfred - As a comment, you shouldn't insert an "edited by" comment when you edit something in from a follow-on answer. Just try to integrate the new content as if they had written it in the first place. We can see who edited from the revision history.

Comment: @BradLarson. Thanks. I just made it to inform moderators / others to understand that the edit is not made by the OP and to make it easy for you guys to understand the part I attached. I know that you guys will remove my name after a review, and "edited by" is definitely irrelevant.

Comment: @blasteralfred - Actually, the only reason I saw this was due to your flag on the answer. Others won't, because we don't review every edit (we would be simply overwhelmed if we had to). It's best to edit things into their final shape and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a `<table>` is perfectly fine to use in this case. Here's some basic markup and formatting to get you started.

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/Qz3cq](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/Qz3cq/)

Answer (score 0):

See [Drawing a tournament bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181703/drawing-a-tournament-bracket-css-html-based-on-php-dataset)

Comment: Thank your for that link it is helpful. I thought i can make it without tables